# Ionic - 'platform add android' Comand failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: java, android, cordova, environment-variables, ionic-framework

Please help me get my Windows 8/Ionic/Cordova/Android environment setup correctly.

I'm trying to use the command 'add platform android' but am unable to get it to work.
 I have seen similar posts to this but none quite the same.

I've tried un-installing Cordova and Ionic and reinstalling them as recommended here http://tinyurl.com/ogxb8u5 but it has no effect.

[image: Heres's the output of the command]
I assumed my environment variables are OK because ant, android , java and node commands are working fine, as are Cordova and ionic, as seen in the tests below.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe you can add `--verbose` to your command to get more error output. `ionic platform add android --verbose`. Hopefully some more errors come out.

Comment: Did you try the update as suggested in a comment to an answer the SO question you link? `npm update -g cordova`

Comment: thanks - i was wondering about that - I'll give it a go...

Comment: @ Guillem Vicens - yes I tried that...didn't fix the problem although looking forward to testing it with the --verbose tag to try and see what's going on underneath

Comment: this appears to be relevant although I don't know how to use it in a practical way https://gist.github.com/domenic/2790533#non-portable-apis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry don't have enough privilege to comment on your question. 
I had faced similar issue.
run this command before adding android platform,

C:\your\Directory>npm link cordova

C:\your\Directory>npm link ionic

then go for,

C:\your\Directory>ionic platform add android

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer - What exactly is happening here? Does this link the current directory to Cordova ? Or does it link Node to Cordova in the current directory only? What do you think caused the origional problem - is Cordova not linked to the project already ?- Just trying to make sense of everything because I am new to Cordova and Ionic

Comment: Feel Cordova was not being linked to the project directory. I was getting same "code ENOENT" issue. Also, Ionic uses Cordova proper at the core. Hence these commands link cordova first to the project directory then, link ionic to the current directory. Note, you must have cordova and ionic installed globally(with -g flag). The steps that I've mentioned helped me overcome the issue that I was facing. Yes, there are different options like navigating to c:\..\Appdata\Roaming deleting some stuff, updating cordova at global level and stuff like that (pretty long process). Try if these commands help

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, running node as administrator solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Go back to your cd
- type:  `bower--install-dev platform`
- Type: `cordova platform add android` (not ionic run)
  I did it, it works here.